# List of functions in the prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to be able to get a list of functions on different JavaScript objects, but specifically String and other primitives.  I thought I would be able to somehow use String.prototype and magically get a list of the functions in the prototype but no dice.  Any ideas?

I also tried using underscore.  For example

```
_.functions("somestring");
```

...doesn't do it for me.

Comment: try `console.log(new String().__proto__);`

Comment: that doesn't seem to work in node.  i tried in firebug console and didn't see the list either.  fb spits out String { formatUnicorn=function(), truncate=function(), splitOnLast=function()}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use [getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) for that, it returns an array of all properties, enumerable or not

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype)
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gTyLs/)

If you need only the functions (which would only exclude `length` I think ?) you could filter

```
var fns = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype).filter(function(itm) {
    return typeof String.prototype[itm] == 'function';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gTyLs/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem is, the members of the primitive's prototype are not enumerable. So, we have to use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames), which will give even the non-enumerable properties, to get them.

You can write a utility function, like this

```
function getFunctions(inputData) {
    var obj = inputData.constructor.prototype;
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).filter(function(key) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]).indexOf("Function") + 1;
    });
}
console.log(getFunctions("Something"));
console.log(getFunctions(1));
```

This filters all the properties which are Function objects and returns them as an Array.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using `typeof obj[key] === "function"`?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Both underscore.js and jQuery use this method to determine the type of objects. So, I prefer this.

Comment: Do you know if there is some benefit to use this over `typeof`? (not a criticism at all, just curious)

Comment: @p.s.w.g For the function type there is no problem, but it messes up [array, null and objects](http://ideone.com/V99XMy), and Crockford also mentions this behaviour [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html)

Comment: `typeof` doesn't "mess up". Arrays, objects and `null` are all of type `object` in javascript, so it returns exactly what it's supposed to return!